# VSO Build not able to download packages

Tags: nuget, azure-devops

I have the following nuget.config file and bellow is the file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="Packages" />
    </config>
    <packageRestore>
        <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    </packageRestore>
    <packageSources>
        <!-- Ditch all the Global NuGet package sources we only want a 
         single private NuGet repo for this project -->
        <clear />
        <add key="private="private" />
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    </packageSources>
    <disabledPackageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="false" />
    </disabledPackageSources>
</configuration>
```

All the packages which exist in the private feed are restored but the same is not happening with the ones in nuget.org:

**From VSO build output**

> Feeds used:
>
> C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
>
> private
>
> https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
>
> ...
>
> Restoring NuGet package AutoMapper.5.2.0.
>
> WARNING: Unable to find version '5.2.0' of package 'AutoMapper'.

This is happening during the NuGet restore step in VSO.

Comment: I don't know if you just mistyped it here in the question's text or if the actual content of the file is exactly as you put, but this isn't correct: `<add key="private="private" />`.

Answer (score 1):

Use NuGet.Protocol.Core.v**3** feed protocol with

```
<add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
```

instead of

```
<add key="nuget.org" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RlZ5.png)
 Inside Nuget.config put the bellow code.

```
  <configuration>
      <packageRestore>
        <add key="enabled" value="True"/>
        <add key="automatic" value="True"/>
        </packageRestore>
    </configuration>
```